# Vaadin 10: Server connection lost, when clicking Button

Tags: spring, spring-boot, button, vaadin, vaadin10

Everytime, when I'm clicking on a simple Button, which should pop up a notifation or other stuff I am instantly getting the Notification: Server connection lost, trying to reconnect...
I have the same problem when i'm navigating on a view, that contains a grid!
I have the problem since I'm using Vaadin10
I hope anybody can help me...

Comment: How did you create the project? How are you running it? Are you able to share the code for the view with the grid?

Comment: Do you have a click handler on the button?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me... I did everything right ... I crated the Project with Spring Initilizr and it worked when I deleted Vaadin and added the dependencies manually...

Comment: MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely the same issue. 
I managed to create web app with Vaadin Flow 12.0.4 and Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE.
Unfortunately if Thymeleaf dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

has been added, then Vaadin button doesn't work. **Remove Thymeleaf dependency and your Vaadin Flow will work into Spring Boot.**
In addition maybe if you tried playing with older versions of these two frameworks you will avoid this problem, but it is not guaranteed that something else will not being broken.
Anyway to me this is Vaadin Flow bug, and also I will strongly recommend do not use Vaadin and Spring Boot simultaneous in production.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me!  I was wondering why it was just working when I created a new project but I just didn't use Thymeleaf in it. Anyway thank you!